# Slowly decaying ACF plot = indicative of trend or AR(1) process?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

[image]

I am required to interpret a suitable ARIMA model for the above ACF and PACF plot. My first instinct from the slowly decaying ACF plot and the sharp drop after lag 1 of the PACF tells me this is an AR(1) process, so a possible model would be ARMA(1,0).

BUT could the slowly decaying ACF indicate the presence of a trend and thus, a need for differencing? As such, another possible ARIMA model could also be ARIMA(1,1,0).

EDIT:
Maybe not necessarily a trend but that the series is NOT stationary (since the values are significantly correlated to each other until lag 4) and therefore requires differencing

Comment: By trend, do you mean stochastic trend that is generated by a unit root? Because otherwise I do not see a reason for differencing. And certainly the ACF does not look like one from a stochastic trend; that would be way more persistent.

Comment: Sorry, maybe not necessarily a trend but that the series is NOT stationary (since the values are significantly correlated to each other until lag 4) and therefore requires differencing

Comment: There are two mistakes in one sentence. First, autocorrelation does not imply nonstationarity. Second, presence of autocorrelation does not warrant differencing. (And a side note: differencing will not remove autocorrelation in this case – try and see.)